# How to get content value out of meta tag in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this list of meta tags in my view HTML (after the page loads). The tag is generated dynamically,

```
@meta = "\n  <meta content=\content1\">\n  <meta content=\content2\">\n  <meta content='content2\">\n  ....... <meta content=\"2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900\" name=\"r_end\">\n \n"
```

I wanted to fetch the value `2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900` inside `content` i.e.`<meta content=\"2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900\" name=\"r_end\">`. Is there a way to get the value of the content from the meta tag.

Comment: If it is _your_ view, you probably have put it there.

Comment: this meta tag is generated dynamically, I have to grab the value and pass it some other variable.

Comment: How is it generated? Could you please add code of your view? Not generated html but your `.html.erb` (or maybe slim) view

Comment: It is not there in any of the erb files, we have content management tool from there we are fetching the entire HTML and rendering it. I wanted to grab the value in the  "content" and store in some variable and pass on.

Comment: @Sam _"we are fetching the entire HTML and rendering it"_ – so you have the HTML containing the `<meta>` tag as a string?

Comment: @Stefan yes the final generated HTML at my end contains that meta tag not as a string but as an HTML element.

Comment: @Sam _"not as a string but as an HTML element"_ – what do you mean by that? What kind of Ruby class is it?

Comment: @Sam There should be code somewhere that generates that string. It is probably located in a place not under your control. You need to search through your entire system to find it.

Comment: @sawa I found that variable "@meta" in my code returns; 

"\n  

<meta content=\content1\">\n  

<meta content=\content2\">\n  

<meta content='content2\">\n  

.......

<meta content=\"2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900\" name=\"r_end\">\n

\n"

Now, how can I get the value inside the content from the list of the meta tags (the last meta tag)

Comment: @Sam Try to extract the code fragment(s) that you think is relevant, and add that to your question with explanation. Hopefully, you will get some help.

Comment: @Sam It should be much easier to find how `@meta` is generated rather than trying to parse `@meta` to extract what you want.

Comment: @Sam that `@meta` value looks very much like a string. You might want to edit your question and include that information.

Comment: @Stefan Done, edited it !

Comment: @Sam is the CMS you're fetching the data from part of your Rails setup (like a gem or engine)? If so, you should dig into its code to find the source of that meta tag. You might be able to retrieve it directly or maybe provide the value yourself explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a `@meta` variable containing some HTML snippet as a string:

```
@meta = <<-HTML
  <meta name="foo" content="content1">
  <meta name="bar" content="content2">
  <meta content="2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900" name="r_end">
HTML
```

You can use [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/) to parse it:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(@meta)
doc.at_css('meta[name="r_end"]')['content']
#=> "2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900"
```

[`at_css`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#at_css-instance_method) returns the first element matching the given CSS selector and [`[]`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#%5B%5D-instance_method) returns the value for the given attribute.

Answer (score 0):

How about a using simple regular expression to capture the value using [**`String#scan`**](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan).

This will work only if the name of metatag doesn't change

```
@meta = "\n  <meta content=\content1\">\n  <meta content=\content2\">\n  <meta content='content2\">\n  ....... <meta content=\"2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900\" name=\"r_end\">\n \n"

@meta.scan(/content=\"(.*)\" name=\"r_end\"/) 
#=> [["2019/01/10 09:59:59 +0900"]]
```

Explanation:

The above code will capture the value of `content` with metatag `name="r_end"`

If you think there might be some other HTML elements with `name="r_end"` you might need to add some other identifier in the regex

Comment: Obligatory links: [You can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477037), [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: But as OP said he has the value in @meta as a string so it should work for the string as opposed to parsing whole HTML

Comment: What if due to a small change the attributes are rearranged, and `name` comes before `content`?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility where it would fail